# HTTPS and share

Tags: https, facebook-sharer

I'm writing a Video streaming site with facebook integration. We share videos using meta tags. I recently created ssl for my web server so I can use og tags to make shared videos available for facebook users using secure browsing. Everything was working fine until all of a sudden facebook can not fetch any https content from my site any more. I can not debug the problem because facebook doesn't show any errors why it can not use my ssl any more. I don't see any errors in my web server's log and Facebook debug tool doesn't give any details too. I can open the https url via my browser but facebook seems having problem with it. here is my [url](https://tv-fa.com/index.php/videos/frontend/videos/show_video/6)

Answer (score 1):

I have parsed two urls on the Facebook OG Debugger.
The report is this:

HTTP REQUEST - NO ERRORS (working fine)

HTTPS REQUEST - OG image error

**ERROR:**

> Unable to download og:image:  The image referenced by the url of
>   og:image tag could not be downloaded.

[OG Report](http://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/og/object?q=https://tv-fa.com/index.php/videos/frontend/videos/show_video/6)

Since your SSL is suspicious, it seems the reason why it's not working.